# Create a Utility function for UIActivityIndicator to show and hide depending on the condition in controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Hello I have created a swift file in which I wrote some utility functions which I used in multiple controllers. I also wrote function for `UIActivityIndicator`. But somehow its not working as expected.

Here is my function

```
static func showIndicatorView(backgroundView: UIView,controller: UIViewController)->UIActivityIndicatorView{


        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        let backgroundView = UIView()

        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 05
        backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundView.opaque = false
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)

        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        let loadingLabel = UILabel()
        loadingLabel.text = "Loading..."
        loadingLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let textSize: CGSize = loadingLabel.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: loadingLabel.font ])

        loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height)
        loadingLabel.center.y = loadingIndicator.center.y

        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width + 70, 50)
        backgroundView.center = controller.view.center;

        controller.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
        backgroundView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        backgroundView.addSubview(loadingLabel)
        return loadingIndicator

    }
```

I am doing this in controllers in order to show and hide the indicator

**show**
    Utility.showIndicatorView(backgroundView, controller: self).startAnimating()

**hide**

```
Utility.showIndicatorView(backgroundView, controller: self).startAnimating()
```

Sometimes UiIndicatorView background doesn't remove from the controller. Please check my code and let me know how can I show and hide the uiindicator in one or two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for your loading view and add functions to show and hide the view like this:

```
import UIKit
class LoadingView: UIView {

override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    let backgroundView = UIView()

    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 05
    backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
    backgroundView.opaque = false
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)

    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    let loadingLabel = UILabel()
    loadingLabel.text = "Loading..."
    loadingLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let textSize: CGSize = loadingLabel.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: loadingLabel.font ])

    loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height)
    loadingLabel.center.y = loadingIndicator.center.y

    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width + 70, 50)
    backgroundView.center = self.center;

    self.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    backgroundView.addSubview(loadingLabel)
}

convenience init () {
    self.init(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func showLoadingView() {
    if let rootViewController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        rootViewController.view.addSubview(self)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(rootViewController.view)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
}

func hideLoadingView() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}
}


// Get the visible ViewController
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

            if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController where top.view.window != nil {
                return topViewController(top)
            } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presented)
        }

        return base
    }
}
```

Then init your loading view in your ViewController.

```
let lv = LoadingView()
lv.showLoadingView()

lv.hideLoadingView()
```

Comment: I am creating custom uiindicatorview with a background. please check. I want to show and hide that one.

Comment: Yes I understand, create a class for your backgroundView, add it the UIIndicatorView, and then show/hide this view(backgroundView) from your ViewController

Comment: thank you very much.. I am getting these errors. https://gyazo.com/9022f39a33f3b851fdb7952cc1e338de

Please have a look

Comment: Import UIKit at the beginning of your class

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot a part of code that get the current visible ViewController. It should work now

Comment: okay one error is gone. and for the other error I did this 
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

and I try to show the loading view but it is not showing

Comment: Okay I get it. what is happening is spinner is moving in front of wifi icon on the top ? why is that ? This is not what my code is doing

Comment: I added the convenience init too

Comment: You have to adjust the position of your views

Comment: do you know what I am saying. It is showing spinner on the top in front of wifi icon

Comment: well I don't think so thats the issue. My code works fine. the only issue is I don't know how to create a proper utility function

Comment: If your spinner is at the top left corner, just move it. I showed you how to easily display/hide a loading view, but it's a different manner to do than you, so the views are not displayed as exactly as you did before.

Comment: can we discuss in chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107824/discussion-between-hellosheikh-and-max).